# Reading QML JavaScript values within gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, qml

I'm debugging a crash in a QML application. I can reproduce the crash in gdb and look at the stack trace and variables, but I would like to know what QML objects and functions they represent. Is there a simple way to find that out?